# Can't get equal column heights after text extends page boundary

Tags: css

I have the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/x200bfjs/

As you can see, if the panel text does not exceed the page size, the panels fit perfectly in proportion to each other, else there is an undesired effect of the panel heights not matching, or text bleeds out of the panels. Giving the panels a min-height property fixes the bleeding of the text, but it doesn't fix the column heights not matching.

Any advice? Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<div class="hm-left">
  <div class="cafe hm-panel">
    <h1>Cafe</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="restaurant hm-panel">
    <h1>Restaurant</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hm-right">
  <div class="services hm-panel"><h1>Services</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  color: white;
}

.hm-panel {
  padding: 15px;
}

.hm-left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float:left;
}

.hm-right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float:right;
}

.cafe {
  background-color: #6B8E23;
  height: 50%;
}

.restaurant {
  background-color: brown;
  height: 50%;
}

.services {
  background-color: #FF8C00;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some problems still with my answer to Jake Zeitz's suggestion, but I have the following, which seems to work for all different scenarios ---Like content of the panels are smaller that document height, and same for when it's bigger.

The solution was to modify the CSS a little with some `min-height` properties, and also manipulate the `hm-left` and `hm-right` columns to match the document height with jQuery.

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  color: white;
}

.hm-left {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  float:left;
}

.hm-right {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  float:right;
}

.cafe {
  background-color: #6B8E23;
  height: 50%;
}

.restaurant {
  background-color: brown;
  height: 50%;
}

.services {
  background-color: #FF8C00;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var doc_height = $(document).height();

$(".hm-left").css("height", doc_height + "px");
$(".hm-right").css("height", doc_height + "px");
```

Answer (score 1):

I added `box-sizing: border-box` as well as `overflow-y: auto;` to each of your containers in order to get exact dimensions for the box as well as keeping the text viewable within the container.

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/x200bfjs/2/

Update:

In order to keep the `overflow: auto` at the page level I had to change the structure of the html.  I put everything in a container and gave that the orange background for services.  Hopefully, that isn't an issue.  Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/x200bfjs/3/

Comment: Thanks for the example. It was a good solution, but I didn't make clear that the overflow needs to be at the page level only (not at the panel level).

Comment: See my update, that will give the experience you are looking for.

Comment: Once again, it was a nice work around, but I've no idea what the length of the text will be, so if the Services text exceeds the height of the other two panels, the orange background is shown on the left side.

Comment: Oh, you gave me a great idea though. With a little JS, I can change the background depending on which side is taller...
`if ($('.hm-left').height() < $('.hm-right').height()) {
      $("body").css("background-color","brown");
    }
    else {
      $("body").css("background-color","#FF8C00");
    }`

If someone doesn't chime in with a non scripty solution, I'll mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: awesome, glad it pointed you into the right direction at least!